# Case statement and Joins

Tags: sql, join, case

Looking at DN7 statement. Guess I am missing somethingin the join area.

Need case to display company.name from company table when ca.code = 128 
or 
When ca.code is 106 carrier.name is displayed.
else ph.name

select

```
--TRANSACATION INFO FOR HT
'148' as 'DN1', --TRANSACTION SET ID
isnull(convert(char(2), d9.code), space(2)) as 'D2', --MAINTENANCE TYPE CODE
isnull(left(convert(char(8), c2.froimaintdate, 112), 8), space(8)) as 'DN3c', ---MAINTENANCE TYPE CODE DATE 

--STATE AGENCY
left(c1.jurst, 2) as 'DN4',  --Jurisdiction Code
isnull(convert(char(25), c1.agencynumb), space(25)) as 'DN5', --Claim Number

--INSURER/CARRIER/SELF-INSURER
 case
  when ca.invmsg like 'CARRIER%' then isnull(left(uw.fedid, 9), space(9))
  else left(ph.fedid, 9)
 end 
 as 'DN6', --Carrier/Self-Insurer FEIN
 case
  when ca.invmsg like 'CARRIER%' and ca.code ='0128' then isnull(convert(char(30), (ca.name)), space(30))
  when ca.invmsg like 'CARRIER%' and ca.code ='0106' then isnull(convert(char(30), (uw.name)), space(30))
  else convert(char(30), (ph.name))
 end 
 as 'DN7', --Carrier/Self-Insurer Name**

    from claim c
join claim1 c1 on c.claimno = c1.lnkclaimno
join claim2 c2 on c.claimno = c2.link2claim
join claim3 c3 on c.claimno = c3.link3claim
join person p on c.patient = p.personid
join employer e on c.empcode = e.code
join cmpolicy cm on c.claimno = cm.claimno
join policy po on cm.policyid = po.policyid
join carrier ca on c.carrier = ca.code
join masttype m on c.casetype = m.mastid
left join company uw on po.uwcompany = uw.code
left join [address] a on c.occurlocat = a.addrid
left join employer ph on e.polholder = ph.code
left join mmi1 mm on c.claimno = mm.claimno
left join dictdata d1 on ph.siccode = d1.datumid        --SIC Code
left join dictdata d2 on c2.claimncci = d2.datumid      --NCCI Class (Occ) Code
left join dictdata d3 on c1.injurnatur = d3.datumid     --Nature of Injury
left join dictdata d4 on c.bodypartid = d4.datumid      --Body Part
left join dictdata d5 on c1.injurcause = d5.datumid     --Cause of Injury
left join dictdata d6 on c1.empstatus = d6.datumid      --Employment Status
left join dictdata d7 on c2.losstype = d7.datumid       --Type Of Loss Code 
left join dictdata d8 on c2.mcotype = d8.datumid        --Managed Care Organization Code
left join dictdata d9 on c2.froimaintcode = d9.datumid  --Maintenance Type Code
left join authent au on c1.adjuster = au.shortname      --Adjuster
left join usermst u on au.authentid = u.personid        --Adjuster
left join authent au2 on c.username = au2.shortname     --User (Preparer)
left join usermst u2 on au2.authentid = u2.personid     --User (Preparer)
left join provider pv on c3.treatprovider = pv.fedidseq --Initial Treatment Provider
left join v_provaddr_master v on pv.fedidseq = v.fedidseq   --Initial Treatment Provider Address
left join cf_data cf1 on c.claimno = cf1.claimno and cf1.cf_id = '00024'    --Notice Date


--Date Function
WHERE froimaintdate = '2016-10-26'
        and c1.jurst = 'TX'
```

Comment: is ca.code 0128 or 128 is it numeric or varchar? and why are you using uw.name in both lines when you say you want the company name in one place and carrier name for 106?  too many unknowns here. to provide a quality response.

Comment: 0128 and 0106 char value.  Yes company name when 0128 and carrier name when value is 106.

Comment: So do you just need to change `uw.name` to `ca.name` on the line showing `0106`?  as it stands it seems you're showing the Company name on both lines.  I would assume carrierName would be sourced from the carrier table.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have the wrong table alias on the carrier line for 106 then... use CA instead of UW?

```
 case
  when ca.invmsg like 'CARRIER%' and ca.code ='0128' then isnull(convert(char(30), (uw.name)), space(30))
  when ca.invmsg like 'CARRIER%' and ca.code ='0106' then isnull(convert(char(30), (ca.name)), space(30))
  else convert(char(30), (ph.name))
 end 
 as 'DN7', --Carrier/Self-Insurer Name**
```

I also assume there's more fields after D7 otherwise you have a hanging `,` at the end.

---Try this to help visualize where the problem is...

```
SELECT C.ClaimNo as C_ClaimNo, CM.ClaimNo as CM_ClaimNo,
C.Carrier as C_Carrier, CA.Code as CA_Carrier,
PO.PolicyID as PO_Policy_ID, CM.PolicyID as CM_PolicyID,
UW.Code as UW_Company, PO.UWCompany as PO_UWCompany,
CA.Name as CA_Name, Uw.Name as UW_Name, PH.Name as PH_Name

from claim c
join claim1 c1 on c.claimno = c1.lnkclaimno
join claim2 c2 on c.claimno = c2.link2claim
join claim3 c3 on c.claimno = c3.link3claim
join person p on c.patient = p.personid
join employer e on c.empcode = e.code
join cmpolicy cm on c.claimno = cm.claimno
join policy po on cm.policyid = po.policyid
join carrier ca on c.carrier = ca.code
join masttype m on c.casetype = m.mastid
left join company uw on po.uwcompany = uw.code
left join [address] a on c.occurlocat = a.addrid
left join employer ph on e.polholder = ph.code
WHERE C.ClaimNo = 'SomeVaule you're not getting resutls for'
```

Either you will get a NULL record because a join is failing due to bad data.
Or you'll get a null value on one of the left joins again due to bad data.
or you'll get a null value on CA_Name because it's actually blank...

Comment: Changed example to ca.code but it is actually pulling from employer table and I am unsure why.

Comment: Based on the names of the joins they look fine.  It appears to me you have a data problem somehwere. likely on or near the left join to company.  So either the po.uwcompany isn't what you expect for this company or there is no record in the comapny table.  To figure this out we would need to see a mockup of sample data showing this problem.  As it stands the code "Looks" fine; but only based on general names, I'd need to See DDL for tables nad PK/FK relationships between the tables.

Comment: I'd run this changing the where clause to a specific claim where the problem is occurring so we can see where the problem is... (added to answer as too long as a comment)